# изменения языка datetipicker в зависимости от языка сайта

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

пробую использовать xdsoft

```
  $(function () {
  $.datetimepicker.setLocale('ru');
  $("#id_date_visit").datetimepicker({
    format: "Y-m-d",
      //format: "d.m.Y H:i",
      timepicker:false,
      //minDate: '+1970/01/02',
      minDate: 0,
      dayOfWeekStart: 1,
      disabledWeekDays:[0,6]
    });
});
```

как в зависимости от того на какой странице находишься поменять ему язык?
русская страница по ссылке localhost/ru
английская по ссылке localhost/en
Как заставить этот таймпикер узнать какой язык использовать в зависимости от страницы на которой находишься?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно сделать так
window.location.href.split("/")[3] после разбиение по `/` посмотреть какой элемент будет для языка и написать там свой

```
if (window.location.href.split("/")[3] === "en") {
  $(function() {
    $.datetimepicker.setLocale('en');
    $("#id_date_visit").datetimepicker({
      format: "Y-m-d",
      //format: "d.m.Y H:i",
      timepicker: false,
      //minDate: '+1970/01/02',
      minDate: 0,
      dayOfWeekStart: 1,
      disabledWeekDays: [0, 6]
    });
  });
} else {
  $(function() {
    $.datetimepicker.setLocale('ru');
    $("#id_date_visit").datetimepicker({
      format: "Y-m-d",
      //format: "d.m.Y H:i",
      timepicker: false,
      //minDate: '+1970/01/02',
      minDate: 0,
      dayOfWeekStart: 1,
      disabledWeekDays: [0, 6]
    });
  });
}
```